# How to make safe Rails PayPal payment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm using this guide https://launchschool.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails to redirect user to special PayPal page via simple get request.

Then website will wait PayPal answer at special hook page to allow the user to get his goods. But PayPal answer is just a simple post request, how to be sure that is a real PayPal answer, not fake request from third side app with the same params?

**SOLVED**

Additional layer of logic is needed. When PayPal sends a post request to our hook handler, we should resend it to special validation address, according to documentation
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/

If it answers with "VERIFIED" - we could continue process the request

Comment: isn't there any secret key shared only between you and PayPal in the params?

Comment: I'm trying to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it mentions `return_url` it's talking about [Payment Data Transfer (PDT)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/).

When it refers to `notification_url` it's talking about [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

These are both similar in that you will send a POST request back to PayPal for verification purposes.  If the data actually came from them, you'll get a VERIFIED result back.  If not, it will be INVALID.

If the sample code included in that guide is not including this call back, then it's not a complete guide (and missing a vital piece of the puzzle.)

Details on this procedure are available in the docs linked above.

Comment: Exact values are:

"return" - that's a my website page, where the user will be redirected to after payment will be completed.
"notify_url" - my website post handler, where the PayPal will send post request with any details of this payment (success or cancel by any reason).
Of cource, they send the data back to me, but how to check its verification? I could send the same post request, and anybody else also could do the same, how to check it?

Comment: Did you even read my answer?  I explained exactly how that works, and the docs I linked to provide the technical detail.  You build a request from the PDT/IPN data, and you POST it back to PayPal for verification.  Their system will then reply back with VERIFIED or INVALID.  If you sent it from your own server, PayPal's verification within the script would come back INVALID, and you should build your code logic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Drew, you are right. I was wrong because of similiar but not exact variable names. Unfortunately, that part is fully missed in the guide. Without it anybody could answer and I will regard this answers as actual PayPal.